# Using Term Store Tree Control

Tags: term-store, managed-metadata-service

I need to use tree control that displays full term store like in navigation settings as shown below.

[image]

Where can I find it, and how to use it in code?

I want to enable user selecting one of the term. I can do this in simple tree view control, but when there are lot of terms rendering can be problem.